# FormBuilder edit build template

Tags: javascript, php, html, formbuilder

form creation page works fine but i need form edit page. i think i need an att
but i dont found. How can I do it?

Render form for admin panel

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZhDHN.png)

```
 var options = {
    //GET DATA ...
}
var formBuilder = $(".form-create").formBuilder(options);
```

Example my database row (json)

{
"type":"header",
"subtype":"h1",
"label":"\u003Ch2\u003E\u0130\u015f Ba\u015fvuru Formu\u003C/h2\u003E",
"access":false
},
{
"type":"text",
"required":false,
"label":"Ad\u0131n\u0131z Soyad\u0131n\u0131z",
"className":"form-control",
"name":"text-1629792064114-0",
"access":false,
"subtype":"text"
},
{
"type":"text",
"required":false,
"label":"Do\u011fum Yeri",
"className":"form-control",
"name":"text-1629792065034-0",
"access":false,
"subtype":"text"
},
{
"type":"date",
"required":false,
"label":"Do\u011fum Tarihi",
"className":"form-control",
"name":"date-1629792096274-0",
"access":false
},
{
"type":"select",
"required":false,
"label":"Cinsiyetiniz",
"className":"form-control",
"name":"select-1629792210826-0",
"access":false,
"multiple":false,
"values":[
{
"label":"Erkek",
"value":"option-1",
"selected":true
},
{
"label":"K\u0131z",
"value":"option-2",
"selected":false
},
{
"label":"Option 3",
"value":"option-3",
"selected":false
}
]
},
{
"type":"text",
"required":false,
"label":"Boyunuz",
"className":"form-control",
"name":"text-1629792252737-0",
"access":false,
"subtype":"text"
},
{
"type":"text",
"required":false,
"label":"Kilonuz",
"className":"form-control",
"name":"text-1629792262338-0",
"access":false,
"subtype":"text"
},
{
"type":"button",
"subtype":"submit",
"label":"Button",
"className":"btn-default btn",
"name":"button-1629792543318-0",
"access":false,
"style":"default"
}

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved  :

```
    var formData = jsondata ....;

    var formBuilder = $(".form-create").formBuilder();
```

setTimeout(function(){

```
    formBuilder.actions.setData(formData);
},1500)
```

You need setTimeout (otherwise err : formBuilder.actions.setData is not a function)